# Calling Azure API Management from UI

Tags: angular, azure, azure-api-management

This seems a simple question for whoever already implemented Azure API Management integration with UI i.e. Angular/HTML project. My question is that if we need to call an API in Azure, 1st need to call Azure API Management URL using it's security key. But UI is passing this Key and from browser any one can see the key using F 12 . API Management isn't integrated with Azure AD.

> So how we can securely call the API Management from UI, if API
>   Management isn't integrated with Azure AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point calling API Management itself - you are calling some API that sits behind APIM. So, get a token for that API and use that in the call. You can then configure APIM to  [validate that token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT)and perhaps use a different method to authenticate itself to your API or pass it on. Your API would then need to validate it. In other words, you still need to secure the APIM to your API call.

APIM subscription key is **not** an authentication feature.

Use MSAL.JS to get a token in your app.